# vba failing to export from excel to pdf if the file already exists

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub printPdf()
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
'On Error GoTo errHandler
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Replace(Replace(ws.Name, " ", "_"), ".", "_") _
            & ".pdf"
strfolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\myPdfFiles"

If Len(Dir(strfolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
  MkDir (strfolder)
End If

strFile = strfolder & "\" & strFile

    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Call closews


exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

I am having an issue with saving the pdf files.
If the file already exists  in the folder and has some changes made to it the macro will crash  with the debugger pointing at the openAfterPulish line and display the following runtime error.

-2214701887(80071779)
 "Document not saved."

My goal is that excel should automatically overwrite the old files. Excel will prompt me if I want to overwrite the file when I am saving it manually but crashes when I run the above code.

Comment: Have you tried checking for the file's existence and just deleting it if it exists, prior to your export?

Comment: That is probably why you code will not overwrite it.

Comment: Yes I tried it and realized that I was getting the error because the file was open in another program therefore it did not have permission to save. Thank you

Comment: That will do it. If you attempt to delete it yourself you can add some error handling to account for that condition. See change to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if it exists and delete it.  In you VBA IDE go to the tools menu and selecte references.  Select "Microsoft scripting runtime"

```
Dim Response As Integer
Dim fs As FileSystemObject

'We can come back to here after an error.
TryAgain:

 If fs.FileExists(strFile) = True Then
      On Error Goto DeleteError
      fs.DeleteFile(strFile, True)     
 End If

 DeleteError:
 Response = MsgBox("Error deleting file. Do you have it open? Try again?", vbYesNo)
 ' If statement to check if the yes button was selected.
 If Response = vbYes Then
     Goto TryAgain
 Else
     Exit sub
 End If
 On Error Goto 0

 ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
      Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=strFile, _
      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
      OpenAfterPublish:=False
 Call closews
```